# Windows 10 TP compatibility with ATI Radeon graphics?

Tags: compatibility, amd-radeon, windows-10-preview

The graphics requirements for Win 10TP are described as "Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver". Is this just a compatibility spec the existing graphics must meet?  Bottom line: my system has ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics. Will Win 10TP work with it?

Comment: It depend on your ATI Radeon graphics card, But DirectX 9 is the minimalist of all now a days So it will surely support win 10.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying DirectX 9 is a minimalist standard that all modern graphics cards should meet?  Is there anything that would tell me if this is the case for my system (for example, some common application that requires this so if it runs on my system it indicates compatibility)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I thought I would provide some more specific information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `dxdiag` in run command it will show you all the details regarding your graphics card

but only if you have installed all the graphics drivers correctly. Here It will also show you

the DirectX version currently installed on your system. If it is greater than 9.xxx then It

will surely run win 10 TP smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is aware there are issues with some Nvidia and AMD cards, all kinds of forums are relating the same issues. Myself my laptop both cards, one internal one add on both ATI cards internal HD 4XXX series the other HD 5XXX both do not work on Win10. AMDs latest win10 driver (15.7) doesn't correct the issue either, there always seems to be things that fall throught the cracks, my cards are rated DX11 but that doesn't seem to matter, Win10s DX12 hype states it is all backwards compatible to DX9 as we all know but theres always that but not all.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  For various reasons, I never tested 10TP, or I might have discovered this.  But it's good to be alerted to potential problems with the actual release.  Can you cite any sources for Microsoft being aware of the problem?

Comment: I was on the site Windows Central forums and they had a link.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just a compatibility spec the existing graphics must meet?

Any card that supports DX 9 or higher is compatible and has the capability to run DX9 software.  Just because hardware supports a software feature like DX 9 does not mean it will have acceptable performance.

> Will Win 10 Technical Preview  work with it?

The **ATI Radeon HD 3200** should support `Windows 10 Technical Preview` provided drivers are released to support it.  The card itself supports both `DX 10` and `OpenGL 3.3` so it meets the requirements.

Windows 10 technically will have Direct X 12 contained within it.  This does not mean your card won't be supported.  Direct X 12 has the capability to run `DX9` and `DX10` software in the respected capability modes.

Some additional information that might be useful to others.  `Windows 7` uses `DX11`, `Windows Vista` `DX10`, and `Windows XP` required you to download and install the DX9 redistributables when it was the current version of Direct X.

[Source 1](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Radeon-HD-3200.9591.0.html)

[Source 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units)

Comment: Thanks.  Running dxdiag showed that DX 11 is what is actually running.

Comment: @fixer1234 - You are running `Windows 10 Technical Preview` or `Windows 7`?  `Windows 10` should already be reporting as `DX12` since that is what is built into it.  `Windows 7` uses `DX11`, `Windows Vista` `DX10`, and `Windows XP` requires you to download and install the `DX9` redistributables.

Comment: Win 7 is what is currently loaded (and I want to keep that way).  Win 10TP is what I'm planning to evaluate in an isolated environment.  I asked this and a couple of other questions to clarify the requirements and how to safely do that.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 10 Icon on an older laptop and Desktop, the Laptop with an ATI Radeon X600 128 MBs running Windows 8.1 Pro, the Desktop running Nvidia also stated my PCs were not compatible to install Windows 10

But when I look at the date it was released, its dated back in August 7. 
I went and installed Win 10 anyway, since if the same basic requirements for Win 8.1 Pro are equal to Windows 10, I took the chance, and it functions better than any version of Windows I ever had on this older Laptop (XP). I hope that helps a bit. Here is the direct download:

There is a direct download link to Windows 10, but I am prompted that I cannot post it - sorry about that. I tried posting it with a couple of screen shots which would have been nice to see, but the moderator wouldn't allow me to do so - sorry.

Another good spec to check for your PC is to "run" the cmd: type > dxdiag and you will receive a pop up window displaying your graphic card's specs, the latest Direct X (Mine was 11) and WDDM 1.0 which meets the specs:

---

```
Time of this report: 8/15/2015, 06:30:19
       Machine name: MOBILEPC
   Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_r9.150322-1500)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Gateway                         
       System Model: Gateway M460                    
               BIOS: Rev 1.0                 
          Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.86GHz, ~1.9GHz
             Memory: 2048MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 2046MB RAM
          Page File: 1334MB used, 1735MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.17415 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: ATI MOBILITY RADEON X600
       Manufacturer: ATI Technologies Inc.
          Chip type: ATI Radeon Graphics Processor (0x3150)
           DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_3150&SUBSYS_0460107B&REV_00
     Display Memory: 1022 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 127 MB
      Shared Memory: 895 MB
       Current Mode: 1280 x 800 (32 bit) (59Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: unknown
         Monitor Id: MS_0000
        Native Mode: 1280 x 800(p) (59.468Hz)
        Output Type: Internal
        Driver Name: atiumdag.dll,atiumdva.dat,atitmmxx.dll
Driver File Version: 7.14.0010.0489 (English)
     Driver Version: 8.360.0.0
        DDI Version: 9Ex
     Feature Levels: 9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.0
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported  *(Apple iPhones and Apple TV work better*)
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Applicable
     Power P-states: Not Applicable
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 3/14/2007 21:42:50, 2759168 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
```

---

Bothe the older Laptop and Desktop, originally XP machines work like brand new... MS should not state the basic requirements and then state that you don't meet them if the specs of the minimum requirements are the same for Win 7 and Win 8.1, correct? IMO, Its a great way to force someone to go out and buy a $2,000 USD Laptop. My PC Desktop had no issues either, I had upgraded the video card back last year though to Nvidia which MS recognized as compatible. Runs as like brand new, which by the way, all my programs migrated except a couple of apps which I never used anyway.

The upgrade is well worth the time. I am enjoying both Win 8.1 / 10 (partitioned on the my Laptop) and Win 7 / 10 (partitioned on my Desktop). These PCs are from the year 2006, almost 10 years old, both purchased from Gateway (Remember the Gateway Stores?) and both from an original XP disc, and both the original HDD, I just upgraded both machines to 4 GB of memory 2 years ago... Thanks MS!

I do have another personal Lenovo with higher ended components :-)

Hope this helps - David.

Comment: Thanks for posting, and welcome to Super User.  In my case, the question has been overtaken by events since it was posted, but your experience may be helpful to others with a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I realized after I posted, this thread was older than I thought. However, as you say, I hope some of the info can be of use to someone doing a search. I am really surprised at all the warning signs MS gave out for incompatibility issues regarding hardware, especially when they offer a link with such lower than expected specifications before installing. I do have the link which one can directly upgrade their Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 machines if need be, I just couldn't post it yet being I am new. The link is from Microsoft. Best Regards.